# Simple Cookie Bar Notice

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using the script from http://cookie-bar.eu/ but for some reason when I set the script to be shown on top of the page, after you dismiss the Cookie Notice, the text from the top of the page is truncated. You can see here how Hello disappears or is truncated:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>cookieBAR</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var expirationDate = new Date();
        expirationDate.setDate(128);
        document.cookie = "dummy=1; expires="+expirationDate.toUTCString()+"; path=/";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Demo</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/cookie-bar/1/cookiebar-latest.js?forceLang=EN&top=1"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by the developer with a new version.